Vue3/Nuxt3 Dynamic component injection not working after build
I am having a many modal popup in my web app. so in my layout i am injecting the modal components as below.
in template
<component :is="CustomModalComponent" v-if="isOpen"></component>

in setup
    watch(useModalStore().modalContent, async (newValue) => {
      if (newValue != "") {
        debugger;
        CustomModalComponent.value = await defineAsyncComponent(async () => {
          return await import(
            /* @vite-ignore */ `../components/${newValue}.vue`
          );
        });
      }
    });

    const CustomModalComponent = ref(
      defineAsyncComponent(async () => {
        if (modalContent.value) {
          return await import(
            /* @vite-ignore */ `../components/${modalContent.value}.vue`
          );
        }
      }),
    );

modalcontent holds the path to the component file. all modals are of the following path components/<pagename>/modals/modalname
Now this code is working seamlessly in my local when i launch the application using nuxi dev
But the real problem comes when i build this to deploy on a server. I am using nuxi generate and used npx serve .output/public to run the build in local. All the modals are not working. instead i get the mime type error because the file is not found.
